# TinyOs nesc Packet acknowledge

Tags: communication, tinyos, nesc

I want to write a mote-mote radio communication program, and want the receiver acknowledges back to the sender. I know the `PacketAcknowledgements` is recommended, but there are some questions I'm not sure about this interface.

```
1. If I use it in the sender mote,should i also uses interface Receive in the module of the sender mote
2. Should I write extra code in the receiver mote? Should I use interface PacketAcknowledgements too?
3. command error_t requestAck(message_t *msg) and command bool wasAcked(message_t *msg) should be used when and where
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No.
2. No.
3. You need to call `requestAck` on a packet you're about to send just before calling `send` from interface `AMSend` or `Send`. Be sure to check an error code returned by `requestAck`, because `FAIL` indicates that the communication layer doesn't support synchronous acknowledgements (it depends on the radio chip and driver you use). Once the packet is sent, i.e., inside event `sendDone` (or later), call `wasAcked`, which returns true if the packet was acknowledged by the receiver.

More info in:
https://github.com/tinyos/tinyos-main/blob/master/tos/interfaces/PacketAcknowledgements.nc

Comment: How long will the packet be considered timed out? If the packet is timed out, can I use the PacketLink interface to retry or just call AMSend again in AMSend.sendDone?

Comment: Well, `PacketLink` is an interface. The question _can I use interface A to do B?_ doesn't really make sense. Show me a particular implementation of this interface for your radio chip (if any) and I'll be able to tell you if it's suitable.